# Lecithin content in various oils?

Tags: nutrition, fats

How much lecithin is in various plant oils like olive, sunflower, soybean, canola, safflower, avocado, palm, coconut, etc.? Or in animal fats?

<sup>cf. R. W. Bernard, [*Science Discovers the Physiological Value of Continence*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=4137) (Mokelumne Hill, Calif.: Health Research, 1957), which mentions lecithin 134×!</sup>

Comment: please do not crosspost ... https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/115037/lecithin-content-in-various-oils .... delete any duplicate posts

Comment: I do not mind if you cross-post, but please do link between them. The point of SE is to help people find answers to questions. We shouldn't hinder that goal with silly gamification rules.